# How to check max date of each input file , if it matches with previous week start date then only process?

Tags: talend

I have 25 countries data file has week wise data in CSV format which we get every Monday in ftp location, I just need to consolidate all the files into one file which I am able to do.

In each data file there is "Week" column and now I need to check whether latest week data is there in file or not , if not there send the mail saying file does not have latest data.

For example next Monday is on 16th March so max week in file should be 9th March.
How can I apply that logic?
Using tAggregateRow and tJavaRow I am able to get the max week of each file but how to design job after that?

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps you want to follow are:

1. Keep the expected max date in a global variable at the start of
   job. In this example it should be 9th March.
2. Read each file one by one and get the max of week date and if it
   matches the global variable then do not send email. Otherwise send
   the email.

So an example job flow might look like:

```
tFileList---iterate--->tFileInputDelimited--->tAggregaterow--->tJavaRow---RUN IF condition(based on if SendEmailflag is Y)--->tSendMail
```

The tAggregateRow should get the max week date.

In the tJavaRow you should compare if `input_row.maxdate == globalmaxdate(9-march)` and based on this set another flag `SendEmailFlag=Y` or `N` with it defaulting to `N`.

Comment: @garptimzn  I am new to talend can you tell me in detail.